# bash append values if keywords are present in the file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

i have made a slight change in my request.Sorry for doing that, kindly help

i have a web ui where user will be passing values and the output will be saved to a file say test with the following contents .

These below mentioned values will change according to the user_input

Just gave here one example

Contents of file test is given below

```
Gateway oe:value 3.3.3.3
Hostname oe:value test.test.com
IP_Address oe:value 5.5.5.5
Netmask oe:value 255.255.254.0
Primary_DNS oe:value 1.1.1.1
Secondary_DNS oe:value 2.2.2.2
```

in this example there are six keywors present (Gateway, Hostname, IP_Address,Netmask,Primary_DNS,Seconday_DNS). sometimes user may fill only 4 fileds then there will be only four keywords.

what i am looking for is, if the keyword Gateway is present in the file test, append its corresponding value with the keyword (here Gateway=3.3.3.3) to test1. Hostname is present, it should appned the value  hostname=test.test.com to test2. Like that for all the keywords.

```
Expected output of test1 as per this example

Gateway=3.3.3.3

Expected output of test2

hostname=test.test.com

Expected output of test3

IPADDR=5.5.5.5

Expected output of test4

Netmask=255.255.254.0

Expected output of test5

DNS1=1.1.1.1

Expected output of test6

DNS2=2.2.2.2
```

Kindly help

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: show how should look the final `file2` contents

Comment: To address above question _what if the one keyword missing_; OP says: - - _verify all the keywords on the left handed sides are present and if present, append there corresponding values to a new file_. I understand it that if all are present, output. If not, don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

ECHO='echo -e'
for field in `cat test | awk {'print $1'}`
do
        case "$field" in
                Gateway)        value=$(cat test | grep -i Gateway | awk {'print $3'})
                                $ECHO "Gateway=${value}" > test1
                                ;;
                Hostname)       value=$(cat test | grep -i Hostname | awk {'print $3'})
                                $ECHO "Hostname=${value}" > test2
                                ;;
                IP_Address)     value=$(cat test | grep -i IP_Address | awk {'print $3'})
                                $ECHO "IP_Address=${value}" > test3
                                ;;
                Netmask)        value=$(cat test | grep -i Netmask | awk {'print $3'})
                                $ECHO "Netmask=${value}" > test4
                                ;;
                Primary_DNS)    value=$(cat test | grep -i Primary_DNS | awk {'print $3'})
                                $ECHO "Primary_DNS=${value}" > test5
                                ;;
                Secondary_DNS)  value=$(cat test | grep -i Secondary_DNS | awk {'print $3'})
                                $ECHO "Secondary_DNS=${value}" > test6
                                ;;
        esac
done
```

Comment: hi tasos boo thanks for your help  i am looking for the same thing. but i want only the values to be appended if the keyword is present. for eg: if grep -q "Gateway" file; then file2 should contain only 3.3.3.3. These values will change dynamically. These are user input. it can be 4.4.4.4 or 5.5.5.5

Comment: @catchvenki Don't put more requirements to comments of answers, add them to your original question.

Comment: @catchvenki i added what you want, but see edit comment fyi!

Comment: i thought that these are user input. Anyway waiting for the OPs reponse and i will correct it!

Comment: @catchvenki the single-line command is the correct one according to what    jm666 said

Comment: @catchvenki see the edited answer i just posted. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

*verify all the keywords on the left handed sides are present and if present, append there corresponding values to a new file*:
A solution in awk for which you first feed a perfect solution sample (file `perfect_set`) and then challenge it with another set:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {               # process perfect_set file
           if($1 in a);        # process each keyword $1 only once
           else {
               a[$1]           # store keyword to memory
               c++             # increment counter
           }
           next                # next record
       }
       $1 in a && a[$1]=="" {  # if $1 in latter file in a and seen first time
           a[$1]=$0            # set $0 to a[$1]
           c--                 # decrement counter
       }
       END {                   # after processing all files
           if(c==0)            # if all keywords from perfect_set were found, c==0
               for(i in a)     # in which case we iterate thru a
                   print a[i]  # and print the records
       }' perfect_set questionable_set # > result_set
```

Output. `print`ing while `for(i in a)` looping results in random output order, therefore the row identifiers are left intact:

```
    IP_Address oe:value 5.5.5.5
    Hostname oe:value test.test.com
    Netmask oe:value 255.255.254.0
    Secondary_DNS oe:value 2.2.2.2
    Primary_DNS oe:value 1.1.1.1
    Gateway oe:value 3.3.3.3
```

But for a non-perfect set::

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{
           # above code not repeated
       }' perfect_set <(head -5 perfect_set)
$
```

nothing gets outputed.